# SDWebImage stopped after Swift2

Tags: swift2, ios9, xcode7, sdwebimage

I spent all the last 14 hours, trying to handle with a issue from the SDWebImage. After I downloaded Xcode 7 and he told me to update my code to Swift 2, these calls stopped to work:

```
let profilePhotoThumb = user["profilePhotoThumbnail"] as? PFFile
    let gender = user["gender"] as! String
    if profilePhotoThumb != nil {
        let imageUrl = NSURL(string: (user["profilePhotoThumbnail"] as! PFFile).url!)
        cell.imageAvatar.sd_setImageWithURL(imageUrl, placeholderImage: ProfileHelpers().loadImageAccordingToGender(gender))
    } else {
        cell.imageAvatar.image = ProfileHelpers().loadImageAccordingToGender(gender)
    }
```

How you can see in my screen shoots, a bizarre behaviour happens: Firstly, when the collection view is load on screen, the layout comes broken, without the placeholder image. Then when i scroll down, I can see some placeholders images, and then when I scroll up again, all the placeholders are in place !

Secondly, is that only the placeholders images are showing. The app is not trying to download the original images from Parse anymore.

Can you help me guys ?

Thanks

[image: At first, the placeholder is missing]

[image: Then when I scroll down, the last cells shows the image placeholders]

[image: And then, when i scroll up again, the placeholders are showing, but without download the images from Parse]

Comment: Have you tried to disable iOS ATS?

Comment: @KenBoreham I have disabled now, but the behaviour stills the same =/

Answer (score 1):

We're having similar issues since the launch of iOS9. If others have found an answer would love to hear them.

I do note that SDWebImage is reporting several errors with iOS 9 including this one related to cache:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/1314